# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list JavaScript while using array.join(' ') method

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a color guessing game in javascript. There is an Array of colors. When user guess a color, it will be matched with the target value.

- onload method is called from body.

  1. A prompt will be shown to ask to enter a color value.
  2. when the entered value is matched, the while loop will be terminated.

I have used a .join() array function to show all the colors for the choice.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guessing Color Game</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var colors = ['aqua', 'black', 'cyan', 'gold', 'green', 'indigo', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy',
                    'olive', 'orange', 'pink', 'red', 'silver', 'teal'];

var target;
var guess_color;
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;

function do_game(){

// it generates random number between 0 to 14
var random_number = Math.random() * (colors.length - 1)

// since Math.floor reduces 13.999 to 13, we have to add 1 for making upto 14
var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number) + 1
var target = colors[random_number_integer]

    while(!finished) {

        guess_color = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n"+
                             colors.join(" "); +
                            "\n\n What color am I thinking of ?");

        guesses += 1;
        if ( guess_color == target){
            finished = true;
        }
    }

}

</script>

</head>
<body onload = "do_game()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to remove the semicolon after colors.join(" ")

Comment: Remove `;` after `colors.join(" ")`.

Comment: And start using semicolons where they are supposed to be.

Comment: You are also missing semi-colons from critical locations.

Comment: @Russ: To be fair, none of the locations is actually critical, the horror that is Automatic Semicolon Insertion will handle all of the above correctly. Still, I'd put them where they belong rather than falling back on an error-correction mechanism.

Comment: https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/ - the referenced github thread is both sad and amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon from `colors.join(" ");` from the string concatenation operation you are performing to create the argument given to `prompt`, so it becomes:

```
guess_color = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n"+
                         colors.join(" ") +
                        "\n\n What color am I thinking of ?");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra semicolon that breaks your syntax:

```
 guess_color = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n"+
                             colors.join(" "); +
                            "\n\n What color am I thinking of ?");
```

Should be

```
guess_color = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n"+
                             colors.join(" ") +
                            "\n\n What color am I thinking of ?");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        guess_color = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n"+
                         colors.join(" "); +
                        "\n\n What color am I thinking of ?");
```

remove the `;` after `colors.join(" ")`